# Как разместить 3 блока снизу по центру?

Tags: html, css, позиционирование

Всем привет! У меня есть 3 блока - подскажите как их разместить снизу по центру друг за дружкой без промежутков, чтобы такое положение сохранялось для всех разрешений экранов? Причем ширина блока `trail-end` должна быть произвольной

```css
.mad-breadcrumbs {
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}
.trail-end {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold";
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: orange;
  width: 250px;
  height: 48px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 41%;
}
.trail-end-right {
  background-color: red;
  height: 48px;
  width: 18px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 90%;
}
.trail-end-left {
  background-color: green;
  height: 48px;
  width: 18px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="mad-breadcrumbs">
  <span class="trail-end-left">Л</span>
  <span class="trail-end">Товары</span>
  <span class="trail-end-right">Р</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<style type="text/css">
    .mad-breadcrumbs {
        display: table;
        height: 300px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .mad-breadcrumbs .vertical-align {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: bottom;
    }

    .trail-end-left {
        background-color: green;
        display: inline-block;
        float: left;
        width: 18px; height: 48px;
    }

    .trail-end {
        background-color: orange;
        color: #fff;
        display: inline-block;
        float: left;
        font-family: "HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold";
        font-size: 18px;
        height: 48px;
        text-align: center;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }   

    .trail-end-right {
        background-color: red;
        display: inline-block;
        float: left;
        width: 18px; height: 48px;
    }
</style>

<div class="mad-breadcrumbs">
    <div class="vertical-align">
        <span class="trail-end-left">Л</span>
        <span class="trail-end">Товары</span>
        <span class="trail-end-right">Р</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: я не указал, но ширина элемента должна быть относительной, т.к. в ней содержатся названия.
"и пропишите желаемую позицию по 0Y" а вот это как сделать для адаптивной страницы или вы предлагаете каждый раз создавать медиа запросы?

Comment: @Вася странное у вас понимание относительности, учитывая тот факт, что вы сами задали фиксированную ширину дочерних элементов в коде. Попробуйте предложенный мной выше код адаптировать под свои нужды (сообщение я отредактировал).

Comment: виноват, хотел написать `min-width` Нет, к сожалению, не удается ваш пример адаптировать под себя, т.к. `mad-breadcrumbs` относительно которого позиционируем блок нельзя делать `dispalay:table;` т.к. во-первых в нем много вложенных элементов со своим позиционированием и блоке задана  бэкраунд картинка, которая при таблице сразу же обрезается..